# How to add decoration(border, hintText, prefix icon, sufix icon) to new Autocomplete Widget....?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-form-builder

1. How would you add decorations like border, hintText, prefix icon, sufix icon to new Autocomplete Widget along with validation to check if it is empty...?

I refereed flutter [Autocomplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) class documentation, it was not much helpful....

2. Also if possible, want to have multi select option with chip similar to below images....
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL8JE.png)

Any Suggestions??

Comment: *"How would you add decorations like border, hintText, prefix icon, sufix icon"* - check `InputDecorator` class

Comment: Yes, I already checked it.. There is no "decoration" parameter in Autocomplete Widget classs... Like all other flutter Input field has...

Comment: I mean to say there is no "decoration" parameter....

Comment: as i said, use `InputDecorator` - the docs say: *"InputDecorator can be used to create widgets that look and behave like a TextField but support other kinds of input."* - more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorator-class.html)

Comment: yup that helped... I will post the sample code which might help someone... However can you help for my second question??

Comment: seems you have to add another `Autocomplete` widget when `onSelected` is called

Comment: If possible can you share example code...?

Comment: i never worked with `Autocomplete` so i dont have any working example code

Answer (score 3):

You can use fieldViewBuilder inside autocomplete.

and do whatever you like with TextField like removing border etc..

hope it helps!

```html
 fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                    TextEditingController textEditingController,
                    FocusNode focusNode,
                    VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
                  return TextField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10)),
                    // decoratteion: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    controller: textEditingController,
                    focusNode: focusNode,

                    onSubmitted: (String value) {},
                  );
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my first question...

```
InputDecorator(
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.info,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            hintText: "Search..",
                          ),
                          child: Autocomplete(
                            optionsBuilder:
                                (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                              if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                                return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                              }
                              return _kOptions.where((String option) {
                                return option.contains(
                                    textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                              });
                            },
                            //   onSelected: (User selection) {
                            //   //   print(
                            //   //       'You just selected ${_displayStringForOption(selection)}');
                            //   // },
                            // ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0,horizontal: 4),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(gapPadding: 1),
              hintText: "Search..",
            ),
            child: Autocomplete<Vehicle>(
              displayStringForOption: (c) => c.vehicleno.toString(),
              optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                return Provider.of<VehicleRegProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .tempvehicle
                    .where((Vehicle continent) => continent.vehicleno!
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()))
                    .toList();
              },
              onSelected: (Vehicle selection) {
                print('Selected: ${selection.vehicleno}');
              },
            ),
          )
```

NB: If we remove `contentpadding` property from input decorator we get expanded widget like this

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0,horizontal: 4)
```

[image]